# Spring boot MongoRepository - Store JSON in Mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jackson

I am learning spring boot and am able to create a simple API that takes the array of products (in json ) as input and stores them in MongoDB.

Here is how the POST input looks like

**NOTE:** Number of fields and their name could vary, in some products, it could be 10 and in others it could be 20.

```
{"product":{
    "uniqueId": "6374848",
    "handle": "polka blanket vanilla",
    "title": "Polka Dot Blanket",
    "vendor": "Johnson",
    "type": "Home"
}}
```

I have created `Product.java` model like this

```
@Document
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private Map<String,Object> product;

    public Product(){
        this.product = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    }
    
    public void setProduct(Map<String,Object> product){
        // System.out.println("setting Product attributes");
        // System.out.println(product.toString());
        this.product = product;

    }
    
    public Map<String, Object> getProduct(){
        return this.product;
    }
}
```

Controller Code

```
    @PostMapping("/product")
    public void FeedConsume(@RequestBody Product product, @RequestParam(value = "site_name") String siteName, @RequestParam(value = "site_key") String siteKey){
        
        productRepo.save(product);
    
    }
```

Problem is: I am able to store the JSON object in MongoDb like this

```
{id:OjectId("asdfs"),
"product":{
    "uniqueId": "6374848",
    "handle": "polka blanket vanilla",
    "title": "Polka Dot Blanket",
    "vendor": "Johnson",
    "type": "Home"
}}
```

However, what I want is to store it in Mongo Like this

```
{id:ObjectId("asdfsd"),
 "uniqueId": "6374848",
 "handle": "polka blanket vanilla",
 "title": "Polka Dot Blanket",
 "vendor": "Johnson",
"type": "Home"
}
```

As I am new to Jackson and spring boot, I tried a few `Jackson` annotations didn't work. Any help how can I achieve the solution.

Comment: You can try using individual product fields, instead of a `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: @prasad_ : Number of fields are variable. There can any number of fields.

Comment: You have to know your model first - that is data modeling.